# Let $K=\{(g,g):g \in G\}$ where $G$ is a group. There are no subgroups $H_1,H_2$ of $G$ such that $K=H_1\times H_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

How to formally prove the following:

> Let $K=\{(g,g):g \text{ is a member of G}\}$ where $G$ is a group
>
> There are no sub-groups $H_1,H_2$ of $G$ such that  $K=H_1 \times H_2$

If I think about it it's so easy to prove (even without using groups) as we can't construct **ONLY** members of the following shape $(g,g)$ as multiplication of 2 groups... but that's not formal.

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I made some corrections to you question:  `K=\{(g,g):g \text{ is a member of G}\}`  and `K=H_1 \times H_2`.

Comment: There is **one** group $G$ for which this is possible. If you think about what that group is, it may lead you to the start of an argument for why this can't happen for any other groups.

Comment: By the way, you could have written $K$ as $\{(g,g):g \in G\}$

Comment: @MishaLavrov which group, I'm sure this can't be true for any G

Comment: @jjagmath yeah it's the same, thanks

Comment: It's true for the group with one element :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov can't we say the same for G={}? and back to my question how can I prove this formally rather than saying it's clear to see that...

Comment: The empty set is not a group: it doesn't have an identity. Anyway, my point is that to get started with a formal proof, you'll *need* to use the assumption that $G$ has at least two elements $g \ne g'$, because the claim is not true otherwise. So think about how you can work that in.

Comment: What does "we can't construct ONLY members of the following shape $(g,g)$ as multiplication of 2 groups" even mean? Are you suggesting $K$ isn't even a subgroup? If so, that's false, as $K$ is in fact a subgroup, which you should check.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. Show if one of $H_1$ or $H_2$ is nontrivial, then $H_1\times H_2$ has an "off-diagonal" element.